# returning cout in C++ using inheritance

Tags: c++

Trying to return a sentence out with inheritance but keep getting this error
`invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'void')`

So wanted to know what I am doing wrong, I was playing around with Int before and it was working but now since its string its all messed up.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Knowledge{
public:
    void getKnowledgeJussi(){
        cout<< " coding exp + " << endl;
    }
    void getKnowledgeJarno(){
        cout<< " talking/communication exp" << endl;
    }
};
class Masnad : public Knowledge{
public :
      void getMasnadKnowledge(){
      return  cout << getKnowledgeJussi()  <<  getKnowledgeJarno() <<  " = " + "Masnad with so much XP"  << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Masnad mas;
    cout << mas.getMasnadKnowledge() << endl;
}
```

Comment: you're returning nothing / nothing relevant and expect that `cout` will understand that?? Clarify your interfaces first. You should return strings and string concatenations instead.

Comment: Trying to output a `void` fails  miserably as you see.

Comment: Also, use `'\n'` instead of `endl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you return a void, `cout` won't know what to print. I think you want to return a string like so:

```
string getKnowledgeJussi(){
   return ("coding exp + \n");
}
string getKnowledgeJarno(){
   return ("talking/communication exp \n");
}
string getMasnadKnowledge(){
   return  (getKnowledgeJussi()  + getKnowledgeJarno() +  " = " + "Masnad with   so much XP \n");
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
 Masnad mas;
 cout << mas.getMasnadKnowledge() << endl;
```

**Note**: Don't forget to include the string library:

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: Why the parentheses on the return str??

Comment: Persona;l preference and coding style.  It shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Dam thats just for organization. Its just my coding style , no need